# When you are free vs when you become free?

Tags: sentence-usage

I am texting a friend who might be busy. So I text him  ' leave a message when you are free'? Is that correct?

Comment: Both of them are correct.

Comment: Why not just text the question? Everybody knows there will be a response when the recipient is free, otherwise not (depending on how urgent the message seems).

Comment: Using *become* in that context borders on suggesting that your friend is incarcerated in some way.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you present is so common that nuance plays very little, if any, role in it.

But let's say that you wanted to express the idea that you respect the other person's time; it is valuable and in great demand. In that case, "when you become free" or "when you have a free moment" might do. The phrase "when you're free" is a little too casual to express anything more than that you realize there may be some delay in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Both your examples

> When you are free
>   When you become free

are essentially the same, obviously your friend will **be** free when he **becomes** free.

Since it is a friend, you might use

> When you have a moment
>   When you get a chance

whereas

> When it is convenient

might be considered more polite/formal.